# How to hide API keys using Vanillas JS

Tags: javascript, github-api, api-key

Is this possible? I'm doing a Frontend mentor challenge that connects and pulls Github user information after searching for a user. Everything works and is connected. I'm ready to push my code and submit my project but I would like to hide my API keys. I'm fairly new to JS, is there a way to do this without NodeJS? I've removed the keys themselves but this is where I am fetching the API data.

```js
class Github {
  constructor() {
    this.client_id = CLIENT_ID_GOES_HERE;
    this.client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET_GOES_HERE;
  }

  async getUser(user) {
    const profileResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}?client_id=${this.client_id}&client_secret=${this.client_secret}`);

    const profileData = await profileResponse.json();

    console.log(profileData);

    return {
      profileData,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: you cannot. Better encrypt

Comment: @brk _"Better encrypt"_... encrypt **what**?

Comment: No, it is not possible to hide API keys intended for client-side use from the client. If the keys are in fact for client use (web or app), services don’t expect you to hide them, though.

Comment: Did you know you can make up to 60 unauthenticated requests per hour to the Github API?

Comment: I know my github api key isn't something that will leak crucial data of any kind. I was just wanting to take as much of a professional approach to this project as I could.

Answer (score 2):

Is not possible, any javascript key used on the client-side has to be public, you should use your Github secrets on the server-side only, using node-js and environment variables to avoid adding it to a public repository.

https://medium.com/chingu/an-introduction-to-environment-variables-and-how-to-use-them-f602f66d15fa